# Should I set OnClickListener of ReyclerView's Item inside OnBindViewHolder() method?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a `RecyclerView` and I update it's items 30 times each second. Now my question is :

If I set OnClickListner of each item inside `onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)` method, 30 `View.OnClickListner` object will be created each second. Will this cause a problem or not? Thanks.

```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It will cause memory leak. You can make onClickListener Interface and implement it.

Comment: Not inside `onBindViewHolder`, implement it inside the **viewholder**.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good resource:

[Recyclerview-listener](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
}

public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
    ...
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the approach to implement `View.OnClickListener` for RetcyerView's Items in [this article](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-set-recycleview-item-row-background-color-in-android/)  is very good. It also manages item selection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But it is not good practice. You can set your click listener inside `ViewHolder` And you have `getAdapterPosition()` that will help you to get current clicked item. (May be you need to pass item or something else).
More more information you can see the [blog](https://hackernoon.com/android-recyclerview-onitemclicklistener-getadapterposition-a-better-way-3c789baab4db)

Answer (score -2):

u can use `onBindViewHolder` to set clickable and it work

like this case

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NextModel.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Bad practice, avoid providing context and starting activity from adapter. Better implement OnItemClickListener from @Manzurul Hoque Rumi answer

Comment: This is like my first code and as @Manzurul Hoque Rumi said will cause memory leak.